# Not receiving any data from callback url. Where am I going wrong in Android?

Tags: android

This is my URL post:

```
    String urlParameters = "&consumer_key="+AppSession.getPocketConsumerKey()+"&client_secret="+AppSession.getPocketRedirectUri();
    String request = "https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request";
    URL url;
    try {




        url = new URL(request);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Accept","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setUseCaches (false);

        connection.connect();
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        Log.d("urlparmas",urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();



        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(line);
          response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        Log.d( "response",response.toString());

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();


      }
```

My redirect Uri: MyApp://callback

```
<activity android:name="com.app.account.Register" android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>

     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="MyApp" android:host="callback"/>


                    </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

So, I am just not getting any reply from the callback url. Wondering where I've gone wrong in the code.

Edit:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(line);
              response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            Log.d( "response",response.toString());
```

This produces the error.

Comment: Two things: First, where is your catch block?  Most likely there is an exception thrown that will tell you exactly what is going on.  

And second: do you have internet permissions set in your manifest?

Comment: Let me repost the entire code.

Comment: Have edited and posted the entire function.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the request type, and specify that you need the input stream. You should also check the response code from the request before trying to consume the input stream.

The exception you posted below indicates that there is a problem caused by your server using a custom ssl certificate. You probably need to create a local ssl trust store that your HttpsURLConnection can use. [This blog post](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html) covers a few techniques on how to do this, once you have done that you can use it from your connection

Something like

```
HttpsURLConnection yc = (HttpsURLConnection)pocketUrl.openConnection();
yc.setDoInput(true);
yc.setRequestMethod("GET");
yc.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    // handle error here
    final String responseMessage = yc.getResponseMessage();
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed Response: " + responseMessage);
    return;
}

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: That, and also, why are you using "DefaultHttpClient" exactly? Because as far as I know, you should use either HttpURLConnection class with URL class (lightweight java lib) OR DefaultHttpClient (heavyweight, but more customizable apache lib)

Comment: 12-07 03:43:27.771: W/System.err(4617): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request error. No clue why, though.

Comment: The CertificateException might be caused by your server using a custom ssl certificate, ive updated my answer with a link to a blog post that covers some stuff on how to fix that problem. I also made a mistake in my original answer as you need to use a HttpsURLConnection rather than a HttpURLConnection

Comment: Did read it. And did get rid of all the ssl issues.  
Now, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request error. Not exactly sure what that even means.

Comment: I can only assume that exception is coming from some code that you haven't posted, the string that contains the getpocket.com url isn't used in the code you have posted

Comment: InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         String line;
         StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
         while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           response.append(line);
           response.append('\r');
         }
         rd.close();
         Log.d( "response",response.toString());

Comment: Have edited my code with the entire function that deals with posting and also getting back the response.

Comment: Umm thats a different function to the one in the original question, you will need to re-apply bits of my answer to it (check the response code and message before using the returned stream)

Comment: Shouldn't urlConnection and yc be the same thing in your code?

Comment: 404 indicates that your URL is incorrect (spelling mistake in it or something else like that)